# Use an existing excel workbook to populate with data from UWP

Tags: excel, uwp

I have a uwp app with data grids built from observablecollections I now need to open an excel file to the side of my uwp app & get a list of the sheets to allow the user to select a relevant sheet & then populate a range with data from an observable collection, does anyone have any suggestions or helpful tips/samples?

Comment: I'm confused about your first and second steps, do you mean you want to launch or open an excel file programmatically in uwp app and return the sheet the user select? Can you show more details about it and what you have implemented currently? In addition, if you want to get the data from excel, you could try to use Open XML SDK or parse it manually.

Comment: I need to launch an excel file from uwp & then get the sheets & then populate data from uwp into an excel sheet.

Comment: You can use [LaunchFileAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file) method to launch your excel file. If you want to get the sheets and export data in excel, you could try to use Open XML SDK to achieve it.